# Angular Select List Binding an Object when I was expecting a Value

Tags: angularjs

I wonder if I am going about this all wrong, but here's the issue.

I have a Select List configured like so:

```
<select name="{{ measure.Name }}_MeasureId"
    ng-model="CompleteDataSetViewModel.AnnualRecord.TargetHazardousWaste_Original_MeasureId"
    ng-options="obj.Text for obj in measure.AnnualTarget_Measure_SelectList track by obj.Value"
    ng-init="CompleteDataSetViewModel.AnnualRecord.TargetHazardousWaste_Original_MeasureId = measure.AnnualTarget_Measure_SelectList[measure.InitialFigure_Measure - 1]"
    class="" required></select>
```

This outputs what I want:

```
<option selected="selected" value="?"></option>
<option value="13">Metric Tonnes  </option>
<option value="14">Imperial Tonnes</option>
<option value="15">Short Tonnes   </option>
```

What I then want in my JSON is the value of CompleteDataSetViewModel.AnnualRecord.TargetHazardousWaste_Original_MeasureId to be set to a numeric value of let's say 13.  However, what I actually get is an object like this:

```
"TargetHazardousWaste_Original_MeasureId": {
  "Text": "Metric Tonnes  ",
  "Value": "13",
  "Selected": false
},
```

This is somewhat correct - the right item is picked, but what I am after is simply the 13 as that is the value I want to write to my database.

I have considered doing some kind of mapping exercise to effectively extract the value and assign it, but that feels counter to what Angular appears to be about (I've only been at it 2 days).

I've tried the Angular documentation, but that's left me feeling more confused. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Use [`select as label for value in array`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ng-options to this:

```
obj.Value as obj.Text for obj in measure.AnnualTarget_Measure_SelectList track by obj.Value
```

Without that, you're making it so the one they select is the entire object.

Comment: Definitely useful, but am now finding another problem - when the user picks an item from the select list it puts a blank option in the UI and makes it look like they've chosen a blank option. Strange. It does however send back a value in the way I wanted, so I'll just have to try and figure out this secondary issue. Thanks for help on this one. I was going around in circles trying to make sense of the docs and other questions.

Comment: If you can post a fiddle mimicking your problems it will be easier to help. Also if the answer is good, please accept it.

Comment: Happy to accept. I thought my code would be the cause of the secondary issue, but it actually does replicate in this Fiddle I just created: http://jsfiddle.net/mikerouse/wh8gfcvf/